# How to deploy python script in python http.server

Tags: flask, uwsgi, httpserver

My actual requirement is to expose a python script as a web-service.
Using flask I did that. As Flask I snot a production-grade server. I used uWSGI to deploy that.

Most of the sites suggesting to deploy this with NGINX. Why my web-service didn't contain any static data.

I read somewhere that the queue size for uWSGI is 100. Means Ata point of time it can queue upto 100 requests?

My manager suggested deploying the flask script in http.server instead of NGINX. Can I deploy like this?

Is it possible to deploy a simple "HelloWorld" python script in http.server?
Can you please provide an example of how can I deploy a simple python script in a http.server.

If I want to deploy more such "HelloWorld" python scripts how can I do that?

Also can you point some links on http.server VS uWSGI.

Thanks, Vijay.

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the sites suggesting to deploy this with NGINX. Why my web-service didn't contain any static data.

You can configure nginx as a reverse proxy, between the Internet and your WSGI server, even if you don't need to serve static files from nginx.  This is the recommended way to deploy.

> My manager suggested deploying the flask script in http.server instead of NGINX. Can I deploy like this?

`http.server` is a simple server which is built into Python and comes with the [same warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) as Flask's development server: do not run in production.

You can't run a flask script with `http.server`.  Flask's dev server does the same job as `http.server`.

Technically you **could** run either of these behind nginx but this is not advised as both `http.server` and Flask's dev server are low security implementations, intended for single user connections.  Even with `nginx` in front, requests are ultimately handled by either server, which is why you need to launch the app with a WSGI server which can handle load properly.

> I read somewhere that the queue size for uWSGI is 100. Means Ata point of time it can queue upto 100 requests?

This doesn't really make sense.  For example `gunicorn` which is **one of many** WSGI servers, [states the following](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) about load:

> Gunicorn should only need 4-12 worker processes to handle hundreds or thousands of requests per second.

So by specifying the number of workers when you launch gunicorn with something like:

```
gunicorn --bind '0.0.0.0:5000' --workers 4 app:app
```

... will increase the capability of the WSGI server (gunicorn in this case) to process requests.  However leaving the `--workers 4` part out, which will defualt to 1 is probably more than sufficient for your HelloWorld script.